# Authentication issue with simple upload on Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to my Google Drive file space, and I'm using the following code:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url_goto = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media";

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState==4 && httpRequest.status==200) {
        Firebug.Console.log(httpRequest.responseText);

    } else if (httpRequest.readyState==4 && httpRequest.status==401) {
        Firebug.Console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
    } else {
        Firebug.Console.log('Other status: ' + httpRequest.readyState + ', ' + httpRequest.status);
    }

};
var s = 'Test string';
httpRequest.open('POST', url_goto, true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', s.length);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'MY_AUTH_KEY');
httpRequest.send(s);
```

The problem is that I've the following output:

```
"Other status: 1, 0"
"Other status: 1, 0"
"Other status: 2, 401"
"Other status: 3, 401"
```

...and an exception is thrown:

```
"{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}"
```

Can anybody help me to understand why authentication is not working?
I'm using the API Key retrieved from my Google APIs Console, under section Simple API Access.

Thanks!

Comment: did -@Shirs answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using oauth2 token then you must specify the Bear along with auth token in Authorization header like

httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MY_AUTH_KEY");

Comment: Where can I get this Auth key from oauth2? I can see there are API key, ClientID and scopes but no Auth key. Where it can be found?